# xampp/php - rsync ssh public passwordless

Tags: php, ssh, rsync, xampp, ssh-keys

How can I rsync from php on my development (win/xampp) machine to my testing (Ubuntu) LAMP server using ssh public passwordless key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

install ssh key auth and make an rsync?

[Here](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) is a complete manual how to do this. My Google keywords "rsync ssh folder".

Edit: if you want to share your php projects use something like Git or another version control system  witch is made for this.

Comment: I know that how to set up ssh key and i know how to connect from one *nix box to another. How to do it on windows using xampp?

Comment: you can download freeSSHd for windows and try to connect from your linux system to the windows system. But an easier way is something like GIT ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can either install cygwin and rsync from there, or you try some more lightweight solution mentioned here:
https://superuser.com/questions/129970/minimal-rsync-installation-without-need-for-cygwin

Tyrael